# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql

In the following php code, I am getting the above error. `$strings` stores the fields coming from database as an array. So why is this error coming? Can someone tells me the solution for this problem, please.

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("chatter",$con);
$mvsql="Select body from feed";
$str=mysql_query($mvsql,$con);$i=0;
while($strings=mysql_fetch_array($str)){
echo $strings["body"] . "<br>";
}
require_once __DIR__ . '/../autoload.php';
$sentiment = new \PHPInsight\Sentiment();
foreach ($strings as $string) {

    // calculations:
    $scores = $sentiment->score($string);
    $class = $sentiment->categorise($string);

    // output:
    echo "String: $string\n";
    echo "Dominant: $class, scores: ";
    print_r($scores);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: `while($strings=mysql_fetch_array($str))`: the last iteration of the loop, mysql_fetch_array returns `false` (no more rows). So after this loop, when you go in your foreach, `$string` is `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate until `mysql_fetch_array($str)` returns `false`. I.e. until `$strings` is no longer an array. `foreach` expects `$strings` to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

Add this row in your while loop, and use the foreacn on this:

```
$stringsArr[] = $strings["body"];
```

- Do not use `mysql_` functions, because they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`while($strings=mysql_fetch_array($str))`: the last iteration of the loop, `mysql_fetch_array` returns `false` (no more rows). So after this loop, when you go in your `foreach` loop, `$string` is `false`. Just execute your instructions inside the `while` loop, for each row.

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("chatter",$con);
$mvsql="Select body from feed";
$str=mysql_query($mvsql,$con);$i=0;
require_once __DIR__ . '/../autoload.php';
$sentiment = new \PHPInsight\Sentiment();
while($strings=mysql_fetch_array($str)){
    $body = $strings['body'];

    // calculations:
    $scores = $sentiment->score($body);
    $class = $sentiment->categorise($body);

    // output:
    echo "String: $body\n";
    echo "Dominant: $class, scores: ";
    print_r($scores);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Please also read this post: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860046#12860046) , very useful.

Answer (score 0):

$strings will be FALSE when the foreach starts.
This is because of the while above it. This loop will loop through all records, till mysql_fetch_array($str) returns FALSE and thus terminates the loop.

You should probably put the foreach code inside the while loop or use the while loop to collect the items you need and loop through those in the foreach loop.